# Running quick if statements in Django template language

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-templates

I'm using this code:

```
<div class="stream {% if streams.online %}online{% else %}offline{% endif %}">
```

It seems a little redundant. I'd love to run this code

```
<div class="stream {{ 'online' if stream.online else 'offline' }}">
```

But sadly that doesn't work. Is there a shorter and less messy way of doing what I want?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Can't you use the [`yesno` built-in template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#yesno)?

As in,

```
<div class="stream {{ stream.online|yesno:"online,offline" }}">
```

Comment: Just a note: This cannot work like this: `<div class="stream {{ stream.online|yesno:stream.online,stream.offline }}">`

Comment: string only :-(